# How to aggregate "continuous" records in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this:

```
name        date        record
A           20180725    1
A           20180725    2
B           20180721    5
B           20180721    7
B           20180721    8
B           20180721    9
```

and I hope to aggregate "continuous" records, expected result like:

```
name        date        r1    r2
A           20180725    1     2
B           20180721    5     5
B           20180721    7     9
```

where `r1` and `r2` are the start and end of a group of continuous records.

How to achieve this in sql server in a good way?

Comment: why is row 2 NOT continuous to row 3 in the output - I mean why is that flagged as discontinuous?  Also, what is your order to determine start and end, is record itself the order perhaps?  but why not r1=5, r2=9 for row 2?  It could just be GROUP BY with MIN and MAX

Comment: I *assume* it because there isn't a row with the value `6` for `record`, @Cato. What version of SQL Server is this?

Comment: @Cato  sorry for the ambiguous description. The continuity I want is based on column `record` on integer level, and the aggregation is based on `name` and `date`. So if you insert a row with record=6 following which record=5 in original table, then I will expect only one group of B in output

Comment: @Larnu thank you for help explain, you got my point. I'm using sql server 2012

Comment: are you also breaking to a new group if name or date changes, but the sequence does not have a gap?

Comment: @Cato yes, name and date define their group

Comment: I had a question mark over what it should do if there is a later 'island' of A - for example if there was a future record with A, with record number 56 say - I'd definitely recommend trying the solutions with more data to check, since they get the same output for your test, but might vary if more scenarios are put in.  Interesting question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is a gaps-and-islands problem.  It has a pretty simple solution in your case.  If you subtract a sequence from `record`, then the value is constant when the `record` values are a sequence.

So:

```
select name, date, min(record), max(record)
from (select name, date, record,
             row_number() over (partition by name, date order by record) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by name, date, (record - seqnum)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lead()` function :

```
select name, min(record), max(record)
from ( select *, coalesce(lead(record) over (partition by date order by name) - record, 1) as grp
       from table
     ) t
group by name, grp;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT c1.name, 
        c1.[date],
        c1.record, 
        OA.record
                FROM contTable c1 

                    OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 co.name,co.date, co.record FROM contTable co WHERE co.record >= c1.record
                                        AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM conttable ce2 WHERE ce2.record = co.record + 1)
                                        ORDER BY co.record ASC) OA

                WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM contTable ce WHERE ce.record = c1.record - 1);
```

tO PUT THE BREAKS on code, date

```
SELECT c1.name, 
        c1.[date],
        c1.record, 
        OA.record
                FROM contTable c1 

                    OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 co.name,co.date, co.record FROM contTable co WHERE 
                                co.record >= c1.record
                                        AND 
                                            (
                                                NOT EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM conttable ce2 WHERE ce2.record = co.record + 1)
                                                OR EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM contTable ce4 WHERE ce4.record = co.record +1 AND (ce4.date != co.date OR ce4.name != co.name) )
                                            )
                                        ORDER BY co.record ASC) OA

                WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 0 FROM contTable ce WHERE ce.record = c1.record - 1) 
                    OR
                        EXISTS (SELECT 0 FROM contTable ce3 WHERE ce3.record = c1.record - 1 AND (ce3.date != c1.date OR ce3.name != c1.name) )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
RES.[name], RES.[date], MIN(RES.[record]) AS [r1], MAX(RES.[record]) AS [r2]
FROM
(
SELECT
    K.[record]-dense_rank() over(partition by K.[name], K.[date] order by K.[record]) AS X, K.* 
FROM
TABLE K
) RES 
GROUP BY RES.[name], RES.[date], RES.X
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select SS.name, SS.date, (
select TOP(1) record as [text()]
from t as FF
where FF.name = SS.name and FF.date = SS.date
order by name, date
FOR XML PATH('') ) as r1, 
(
select TOP(1) r2_xml.hour as [text()] 
from  t as TT
where TT.name = SS.name and TT.date = SS.date
order by name, date, record desc
FOR XML PATH('') ) as r2 
from  t as SS
group by SS.name, SS.date
order by 1
```